# Message pattern and send list

Tags: c#, message-queue

I use messages in my application. For example, I have this message

```
public class OrderMessage:IMessage
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I want to send a list of OrderMessage. How can I do it?

I see several ways.

1) Move data from class OrderMessage in class OrderInfo and change OrderMessage.
Then I can make a class OrderList to send a list of orders.

```
public class OrderInfo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class OrderListMessage:IMessage
{
    public IEnumerable< OrderInfo> Orders{ get; set; }
}
```

2) Add to OrderMessage properties IsFinished and SubscriptionTypes and process them.

```
public class OrderMessage:IMessage
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
    public SubscriptionTypes SubscriptionType { get; set; }
}

public enum SubscriptionTypes
{
    Snapshot,
    Updates,
}
```

What in your opinion is the most optimal variant of transfer orders list via Message?

Comment: how to you transfer those messages? And I don't get it why you don't just go with your class `OrderListMessage : IMessage` alone - `OrderMessage` is just a list with only 1 Element

Comment: Asking opinion is subjective which is off topic here, Ask for a objective question.

Comment: I want to get a snapshot or to subscribe to updates on orders so I need to define what I got all the data on the snapshot and are now only receive updates.

Comment: equivalent in the code
var orders = Class.Orders;
Class.NewOrder += orderList => this.MessageProcessor(orderList);
Class.subscribeToOrders();